# EditText and get chars

Tags: android, android-edittext

How I can get number of charakters which I write in my editview? I want check this number because when I write more then 3 I want use alertdialog. How I can do this in simply way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `TextWatcher` for counting char in EditText as:

```
private CharSequence temp;
    mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET);
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);

        TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    temp = s;
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                   // check here length of text in EditText after change
           if (temp.length() > 3) {
                // your alertdialog
        }
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use TextWatcher to for this.

```
    yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Use any of the method to keep track of quantity and show alert if applicable